# Display of image from formbean in struts

Tags: image, forms, struts, javabeans

i am having a string attribute in my form bean which contains the URL (from the web) of the image.
how can i display this image on my jsp image.

can someone suggest which tag to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Struts 1, then you can simply use the following in success jsp-page:

```
    <bean:parameter id="imagePath" name="beanPropertyForImagePath" />
    <img src="${imagePath}" width="20" height="20" alt="" />
```